# Difference between operator and keyword in Java

Tags: java, operator-keyword, keyword

My understanding so far in Java has been that operators are things like:

> `+,-,*,/,%,<,<=,==` and so on...

And keywords/reserved words are things like:

> `boolean,char,int,do,float,double,new` et cetera.

However, reading through a Java book and an online tutorial I see that `new` is referred to as an operator? But how, I thought operators were specifically assigned to arithmetic types? which as I see are only 28. Why is the `new` keyword also referred to as an operator?

Thank you

Comment: Because it performs an operation. Also, `goto` is a reserved keyword (no implementation).

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the excellent tutorial from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) (emphasis mine):

> Instantiation: The **new** keyword is a Java **operator** that creates the object.

Nobody ever said that you can only **operate** on primitive types in the first place. You operate on objects; and yes there are some numerical operators which are restricted to primitive types. Edit: examples for other operators in Java that work on non-primitives would be **instanceof** and **+** (for String concatenation).

Also, step back for a second and consider languages like Scala that do not distinguish between primitive and "reference" types. In Scala, everything is an object. And operators are just syntactical sugar around methods ... operating on those objects.

Comment: Another good example of named operator: `instanceof`. You might also want to point out that the `+` operator is not restricted to "arithmetic types", since it's also the `String` concatenation **operator**.

Comment: Why does wiki define it like arithmetic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)#Examples

Answer (score 0):

**Operator:**
The operator operates the operand for example : a = 2; b = 2 c = a + b; c = 4;

operands ex: a to z and A to Z etc..

**Keyword:**
The keyword is a reserved word which should not be used in the program.

Answer (score 0):

`new` is not an operator, it is a keyword, according to the JLS.

The list of operators is given in [JLS #3.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12) and `new` is not in that list.

Also towards the end of [JLS #15.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) you can see a mention of "new keyword".

Comment: This is also what I came across. I am still confused about which is what. Operator makes sense in terms of +,-,*...and keyword makes sense in terms of char,boolean,int...why should new be an operator. I don't understand.

Comment: @FooFighter what I understand is that, operator perform some actions. same as new perform also some actions. allocate memory and so on.